# Connecting MongoDB ODM to Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, zend-framework, mongo

I am trying to connect Mongo Doctrine ODM to Magento. 
I have successfully connected zend with mongodb. and I dont know how to Connect the both. I have placed Mongodb odm in "lib" folder of magento and i am having the Issue of linking the lib to magento. 
I am trying to "include" the library base class. 
But the library contains many namespaces. 
I dont think magento supports namespace. so its showing error. 
.
Helps are highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a very good question, which is connected with how Magento loads classes.

There are no good way to fix that without changing Magento files.

So the main problem is in lib/Varien/Autoload.php

```
public function autoload($class)
{
    if ($this->_collectClasses) {
        $this->_arrLoadedClasses[self::$_scope][] = $class;
    }
    if ($this->_isIncludePathDefined) {
        $classFile =  COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class;
    } else {
        $classFile = str_replace(' ', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
    }
    $classFile.= '.php';
    return include $classFile;
}
```

`Varien_Autoload::autoload` - this method can only load classes that follow "Pear naming conventions" -- `Mage_Core_Model_Config`.

But if namespaces are used `$class` will contain `Mage\\Core\\Model\\Config`.

So we can add one more check and fix namespace problem

```
public function autoload($class)
{
    if ($this->_collectClasses) {
        $this->_arrLoadedClasses[self::$_scope][] = $class;
    }
    if ($this->_isIncludePathDefined) {
        $classFile =  COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class;
    } else if (strpos($class, "\\") !== false) {
        $classFile = str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);
    } else {
        $classFile = str_replace(' ', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
    }
    $classFile.= '.php';
    return include $classFile;
}
```

Now you can use libraries which use namespaces.

In addition [here](https://gist.github.com/Narno/5813764) you will find code changes list to use namespaces in Magento.

Comment: Olekssi , I tried this one. Its not working. I am saying this in straight. I dont want to confuse you. Can u Connect magento with mongo with the help of doctrine ODM.
If you have any idea, please share with me..

Answer (score 3):

try these approach, i was able to use two separate database on single magento setup.

for that you will have to create configuration, follow the steps below.

in `app/etc/modules`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Deph_Externaldb>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Deph_Externaldb>
    </modules>
</config>
```

in `app/code/local` and be sure to update the database details below here

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Deph_Externaldb>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Deph_Externaldb>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <externaldb_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>externaldb_database</use>
                </connection>
            </externaldb_write>
            <externaldb_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>externaldb_database</use>
                </connection>
            </externaldb_read>
            <externaldb_setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </externaldb_setup>
            <externaldb_database>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[db_username]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[db_password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[db_name]]></dbname>
                    <model>mysql4</model>
                    <type>pdo_mysql</type>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </externaldb_database>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

your config is ready, you call use the below connection string to access the db

```
<?php

    $resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $conn       = $resource->getConnection('externaldb_read');
    $results    = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM tblName');

    print_r($results)
```

Comment: do you know if its possible to use that approach with a mongodb configuration? like :

        <document_db>

            <connection_string><![CDATA[mongodb://localhost:27017/]]></connection_string>

            <dbname><![CDATA[db]]></dbname>
        </document_db>