# How to connect mongodb with magento?

Tags: database, resource-model, mongo

Can anyone suggest me any article or URL's that will explain how to configure magento with Mongodb as model resource for particular module say Catalog/Product. I have tried to find from this [URL](http://github.com/colinmollenhour/magento-mongo) but I am getting getConnection fatal error as mentioned below.

Error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getConnection() on a non-object in /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php on line 322
```

Comment: try [**this**](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16265/connecting-mongodb-odm-to-magento)